# The alert always prints the same value though it should increase in the loop

Tags: javascript

```
for ( i = 1; i <= NumOfText; i++ ) {
    var ipBoxName="MyInput"+i;
    var txtBoxAutoNumbering="<input type='text' name='textbx[]' id='TxtBx'  style='width:50px;' value="+i+" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(txtBoxAutoNumbering);

    var txtBox="<input type='text' name='textbx[]'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(txtBox);

    var Select_SelectionOptions="<select id='SelectOption'><option>Text_Box</option> <option>Text_Area</option><option>Radio_Button</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(Select_SelectionOptions);
    var c = document.getElementById("TxtBx").value;
    alert(c);
    var Select_For_Multiple_Choices="<button type='button' onclick='ChildTxtBoxes()' id='Child_Btn'"+i+">Click for child selections</button><br><br>";      
    $('#NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(Select_For_Multiple_Choices);
}
```

Here I have put an alert to print the value of the textbox represents by "var txtBoxAutoNumbering" variable. Bt it always prints 1 though it runs. y is that?

Comment: BTW, it's nice to include a Fiddle when asking JS questions on SO...  Here is one for your question - http://jsfiddle.net/QkMXS/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating multiple elements with the same ID. This is invalid HTML. As a side effect, when you try to get them by ID, you will only get the first one you created.

Try the following instead:

```
var txtBoxAutoNumbering="<input type='text' name='textbx[]' id='TxtBx" + i +"'                 style='width:50px;' value="+i+" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

And

```
var c=document.getElementById("TxtBx" + i).value;
```